# Mailchimp package not adding email address to list

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using the following laravel package for my newsletters:

**[laravel-newsletter](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter)**.

I have the following code in my `newsletterController.php`:

```
public function index() {
    Newsletter::subscribe('rincewind@discworld.com', ['FNAME'=>'Goti', 'LNAME'=>'Loki'], 'test');
    return 'Ola !';
}
```

Now when i go to: `/newsletter` in my application i see `Ola !`, but when i open my mailchimp dashboard i see don't see `rincewind@discworld.com` added to the list of emails for the list `test`.

I also tried the following method of the mailchimp package:

```
return Newsletter::isSubscribed('codedevakagautam@gmail.com');
```

This email address already exists in the list `test`, i get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Spatie\Newsletter\Newsletter::isSubscribed()
```

What am i doing wrong ? Can somebody please guide me.

Comment: Mailchimp by default requires opt ins to be confirmed. Have you checked to see if you've had an email from mailchimp (might even be in your spam dir). If that is the case, check out their api docs as you can disable this. 

Alternatively more info would be needed, your best bet is going to be to go through the package debugging out at different points to see where its failing. I doubt its a bug in the package however as it's a pretty widely used one.

Comment: @Rick Thanks for your insights :) the docs however don't mention any opt - ins http://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/api-integrations/about-api-keys as required and i did't received a email. I will try debugging , not sure what u mean exactly by opt ins

Comment: Looks like it changed in the last api update. http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/ - you need to set the ip_opt and timestamp_opt values, and then set status to subscribed. Have a search around for 'double opt in mailchimp' as it's been mentioned a few times on SO before.

Comment: I think you not done subscribe with rincewind@discworld.com

Comment: Rick thanks for the heads up !!

Comment: Did you have defined the list `test` in `laravel-newsletter.php`? And Did you install the package correctly?

Comment: @KelvinC i have installed the package just as suggested on the website and also yes i have defined test in my `laravel-newsletter.php` , which is inside the config folder .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Did you push your code to your github repository? I want to check the codes.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik did you check Newsletter::getLastError(); ???

Comment: Did you call `subscribe` and `isSubscribed` in same class?

Answer (score 2):

Please, verify if you have added an entry to the providers array at your config/app.php

```
// config/app.php
'providers' => [
    ...
    Spatie\Newsletter\NewsletterServiceProvider::class,
    ...
];
```

And at aliases array on the same file

```
// config/app.php
'aliases' => [
    ..
    'Newsletter' => Spatie\Newsletter\NewsletterFacade::class,
];
```

Also, you need to import the package on your controller. By doing:

```
use Newsletter;
```

Be sure to import this way.

If you did all of the steps above, now you can try to use the method:

```
return Newsletter::isSubscribed('codedevakagautam@gmail.com');
```

And to subscribe users to a list, you need to send a 'status' parameter.
The possible values for this field is:

- subscribed
- unsubscribed
- cleaned
- pending

See the docs here:
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/

If this does not work for you, you can have a look at this package:
https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api